# JS Fiddles to retrieve data from Opta: Is there a reason these JS fiddles aren't working anymore, or am I missing something?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

I came across this thread on Reddit, which was last updated a year ago. Supposedly, the sample code gives an idea of how to retrieve sports data from Opta. All the JS Fiddles listed there aren't working for me, but I don't really get why. Am I missing something obvious here?

https://redd.it/47jjis